# SAS check if year is IN character

Tags: date, sas, character

I'm new to SAS and trying to do the next:
I have two tables (users & reviews) connected through user_id.

I've merged both via user_id. 
There are two variables I want to use:

1. "date" (of the review. Saved as format **MMDDYY10.**)
2. "elite" (year a user was elite, saved as a **character**)

Elite has different forms (examples):

- empty cell
- 2012,2015,2017
- 2012:2017

How do I check if a user was elite when he wrote the review?

Thanks in advance,
Peyo

Comment: Does `2012:2017` mean that the user was elite for all years from 2012 to 2017 inclusive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This covers the case when a year is not present in the text of `elite` but is included in a range:

```
data test_cases;
input date yymmdd10. + 1 elite $32.;
format date yymmdd10.;
infile cards missover;
cards;
2012-01-01 2012,2015,2017
2012-01-01 2012:2017
2013-01-01 2012:2017
2012-01-01
2011-01-01 2012,2015,2017
2011-01-01 2012:2017
;
run;

data example;
  set test_cases;
  article_year = put(year(date),4.);
  if index(elite,':') = 0 then elite_flag = index(elite,article_year);
  else elite_flag = substr(elite,1,4) <= article_year <= substr(elite,6,9);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `YEAR` function to extract the year from `date`, then use the `PUT` function to convert it to character and finally the `INDEX` function to search the `elite` list:

```
if index(elite,put(year(date),4.)) then ...
```

The condition will be true when the index function founds the year of `date` within the `elite` variable.